# Link does not appear on name in feed "via <Application name>"

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api

I made a wall post using my application, but the link does not appear on the name in "via ."

Here is the code I used:

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
    dynamic paramStatus = new ExpandoObject();
    paramStatus.message = "message";
    paramStatus.link = "application link";
    paramStatus.description = "description";
    paramStatus.picture = "picture url";
    paramStatus.name = "Title";
    fb.Post("me/feed", paramStatus);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I cant even change the icon that appears next to the application name  :(